# Python Error: IndexError: list index out of range(Python)

Tags: python

How come I'm getting this error?
I have 2 arrays a and b containing n integers. My main purpose is to remove a number from list a and b when it appears in both list.
My code:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):

    n=int(input())
    a=[*map(int, input().split())]
    b=[*map(int, input().split())]
    i=0
    j=0
    for i in a:
        for j in b:
            if a[i]==b[j]:
                a=a.pop(i)
                b=b.pop(j)

    m=0
    i=0
    for _ in range(len(a)):
        if len(a[i])!=len(b[i]):
            m+=2
        elif a[i]!=b[i]:
            m+=1
    print(m)
```

The error that i get:

```
    if a[i]==b[j]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Modifying lists while iterating over them is a bad idea.

Comment: Also, you have two lists.

Comment: `a.pop` doesn't return `a`, don't guess.

Comment: I'm newbie, What do you think I should do? Thank you!

Comment: Also Python for loops iterate the elements of a list, not its indices - so `i` and `j` may not be valid indices of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying a list while iterating over it causes unexpected behavior. Your real issue is that you're iterating over the *elements* in `a` and `b` but using `i` and `j` like they are *indices*.

You want to generate a *new* list of elements that appear in both lists.

```
a = [23, 45, 12, 8, 9, 2]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
c = []

for x in a:
  for y in b:
    if x == y: c.append(x)

c
# [8, 2]
```

Now, you can remove these from your lists.

```
for z in c:
  a.remove(z)
  b.remove(z)

a
# [23, 45, 12, 9]

b
# [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

At no point are we both iterating over *and* mutating a data structure at the same time.

Note that `c` could be generated with a list comprehension.

```
c = [x for x in a for y in b if x == y]
# [8, 2]
```

Or using an intersection of sets.

```
c = set(a) & set(b)
# {8, 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a new list will do, use a list comprehension:

```py
c = [i for i in a if i not in b]
```

Otherwise, you can modify the lists themselves in a similar way:

```py
a_copy = a[:]
a = [i for i in a if i not in b]
b = [i for i in b if i not in a_copy]
```

Comment: This offers a solution, but not an explanation of what was wrong or why this works.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from the user question

Seems like he need **non-matching values**

If that's the case then you can make use of set method : `symmetric_difference()`

**Code:**

```
a = set([23, 45, 12, 8, 9, 2])
b = set([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
result = a.symmetric_difference(b)
print(list(result))
```

If you want vice versa of both you can make use of this method : `Set discard()`

Refer these `set` methods it will be really helpful for you :
[Link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set)